# ¿Como bajar la memoria en RAM que utiliza un programa en C/C++?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Descripción**

Como ya sabemos la sucesión de fibonacci esta compuesta por los números: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34. . . Sabiendo esto la tarea es dado un numero N debes encontrar la posición que ocupa en la sucesión de fibonacci.

**Entrada**

Un numero **N** solamente

**Salida**

Un único entero que indique en que posición se encuentra el numero en la sucesión. Si el numero no se encuentra en la sucesión imprimir un -1.

**Ejemplos**

Entrada 1 - Salida 1

Entrada 2 - Salida 3

Entrada 3 - Salida 4

Entrada 1000 - Salida -1

**Mi codigo que excede los 8MB de megas de memoria :( **

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

/* Estructuras para generar nodos */
struct Nodo
{
    short dato;
    //short indice;
    struct Nodo *sig;
}typedef Nodo;

/* Estructuras para generar listas de nodos */
struct Lista
{
    short tam;
    Nodo *ini;
    Nodo *fin;
}typedef Lista;

/* Prototipos de la funciones */

Lista * crearLista();
Nodo * crearNodo(short dato);
short addNodoALista(Nodo *nvoNodo, Lista *miLista);
void imprimirLista(Lista *miLista);
void fibonacciGen(Lista *miLista, short N);
short busquedaBinaria(short miNum, Lista *miLista);

/* Variables globales */

Lista *fibonacciNum = NULL;
short N;

int main()
{
    cin >> N;

    fibonacciNum = crearLista();
    fibonacciGen(fibonacciNum, N);
    cout << busquedaBinaria(N, fibonacciNum) << "\n";

    delete fibonacciNum;
    return 1;
}

short busquedaBinaria(short miNum, Lista *miLista) 
{
    short min = 0;
    short max = miLista->tam - 1;

    while(min <= max) {
        short mitad = (min + max)/2;
    
        if((miLista->ini + mitad)->dato == miNum) 
            return mitad + 1;
        else if((miLista->ini + mitad)->dato < miNum)
            min = mitad + 1;
        else
            max = mitad - 1; 
    }

    return -1;
}

void fibonacciGen(Lista *miLista, short N)
{
    short num = 1, ant = 0, aux;
    while(num <= N){
        addNodoALista(crearNodo(num), miLista);
        aux = num;
        num += ant;
        ant = aux;
    }
}


/* Empiezan funciones de lista enlazadas */

void imprimirLista(Lista *miLista)
{
    if(miLista->ini != NULL) { 
        Nodo *aux = miLista->ini;
        while(aux != NULL) {
            //printf("indice: %3d, Dato: %3d\n",aux->indice, aux->dato);
            aux = aux->sig;
        }    
    }
}

short addNodoALista(Nodo *nvoNodo, Lista *miLista)
{
    // if (nvoNodo != NULL && miLista != NULL)
       // nvoNodo->indice = miLista->tam;

    if (miLista->ini == NULL) {
        miLista->fin = miLista->ini = nvoNodo;
    }else{
        miLista->fin->sig = nvoNodo;
        miLista->fin = miLista->fin->sig;
    }

    miLista->tam++;
    return 1;
}

Nodo * crearNodo(short dato)
{
    Nodo *miNodo = new Nodo();
    miNodo->dato = dato;
    miNodo->sig = NULL;

    return miNodo;
}

Lista * crearLista()
{
    Lista *miLista = new Lista();

    miLista->tam=0;
    miLista->ini = NULL;
    miLista->fin = NULL;

    return miLista;
}
/* Terminan funciones de lista enlazadas */
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿ Como bajar la memoria en RAM que utiliza un programa en C/C++ ?

Pues, normalmente, lo mas fácil es **no usarla** :-)

En tu caso concreto, no es necesario mantener una lista para calcular la sucesión. Tu programa se invoca, procesa, y muere. Generar una lista y recorrerla va a ocuparte mucho mas tiempo y consumirá infinitamente mas memoria que simplemente calcular los elementos de la sucesión cada vez:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( ) {
    int prev = 0, curr = 1, index = 1, toLocate;

    std::cout << "Numero ? ";
    std::cin >> toLocate;

    if( toLocate == 0 ) {
        index = 0;
    } else if( toLocate == 1 ) {
    } else {
        while( true ) {
            int suma  = prev + curr;
            ++index;
            if( suma > toLocate ) {
                index = -1;
                break;
            }

            if( suma == toLocate ) { break; }

            prev = curr;
            curr = suma;
        }
    }

    if( index == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "No se encuentra\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Indice: " << index << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Observa que **no** se ha tratado el caso especial `1`. Dicho número ocupa las posiciones `1` y `2` de la lista.
**Tampoco** se ha tratado el caso del *desbordamiento*, que puede suceder si la suma del elemento actual + el anterior no *cabe* en un entero.

Estas mejoras quedan a tu libre disposición.